# How to make prefetching of videos played from a URL in Swift

Tags: swift, performance, video, collectionview, prefetch

I have a collection view with videos that I play from *cell* *willDisplay* like this:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = cell as? UserFeedCollectionViewCell {
     let post = feed[indexPath.row]
     cell.videoplayer.play(post: post) 

       }
    }
```

The videos take some time to load (some times 1-2 seconds) and I want to improve the performance of the app.

Is prefetching a good idea in this case?  I am not sure what to put here

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) { 
}
```